# -Xpkginfo argument causes Maven to crash

Tags: java, maven

To generate package-info classes, I added the -Xpkginfo argument to the pom

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>${compiler.source}</source>
        <target>${compiler.target}</target>
        <fork>true</fork>
        <compilerArgs>
            <arg>-Xpkginfo:always</arg>
        </compilerArgs>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Unfortunately, this just leads to the following general error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:compile (default-compile) on project
basis-vs-pi: Compilation failure -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

I encountered the error on different projects (using this parent pom). Any idea what we can do about it?

Comment: Try to start maven with -X parameter and add stacktrace information to question.

Comment: Hmm, I can't reproduce this error with Maven 3.3.9 and JDK 1.8 with this configuration. Compiling a project with or without `package-info.java` goes fine. Which JDK are you using? Can you post the full error as well?

Comment: Thank you. It is indeed a JDK 1.7 issue. Ant has an automatic "correction" for that, while Maven does not.